# How to erase a hard drive with unwritable sectors?

Tags: bad-sectors, dd, secure-erase

So I have a hard drive that is failing. I want to erase the data on it before sending it for replacement. I'm trying to use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXX`, but it stops at the first write error. How can I overwrite the drive with zeros, ignoring write errors? `conv=noerror` seems to only affect the input file.

Comment: There is [a bug report in the Debian database](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=415286) about this behavior, but it seems like it's not implemented yet.

Comment: Does `badblocks` also stop on errors? Perhaps you could do a destructive write with that?

Comment: I now also ran destructive `badblocks` to be sure how much bad blocks are there before I return the disk on Monday. It also erased the disk successfully, but it took nearly 50 hours.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try ddrescue instead of dd - it tries harder with errors

Comment: ddrescue successfully erased the entire disk, ignoring the write errors. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. ddrescue is for *reading* from a disk with errors.  it also *writes* to a disk with errors? 2. This answer would be better with an example command.

Answer (score 19):

Parameters I used with ddrescue to erase drive `/dev/sdb` (filled with zeros from `/dev/zero`) and log output into file `log.txt` (replace `sdX` with `sdb`):

```
ddrescue --force /dev/zero /dev/sdX log.txt
```

Comment: To wipe with random data use:
ddrescue --force /dev/urandom /dev/sdX tmp.log

Comment: How do you know when it's done? I did it and let it run for about 20 minutes and it remained at 0.00% rescued. It's an NVMe SSD with bad blocks that I'm trying to erase... the Samsung Secure Erase utility didn't work for me.

Comment: This doesn't mention anything about the drive in question having bad sectors.

Comment: I would add the `-D` option to write directly to the /dev/sdX bypassing kernel cache &c.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to wipe the drive try [dban](http://www.dban.org/)

From the site:

Darik's Boot and Nuke ("DBAN") is a self-contained boot disk that securely wipes the hard disks of most computers. DBAN will automatically and completely delete the contents of any hard disk that it can detect, which makes it an appropriate utility for bulk or emergency data destruction.

Comment: I was going to suggest this.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, dd also has an option `conv=noerror` to skip errors. If you had errors on an input file, and when *not* using `/dev/zero`, you'd want to use `conv=noerror,notrunc` or `conv=noerror,sync` to prevent dd from truncating the output file where errors exist on the input file.

For your query, you might try this command instead:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXX conv=noerror
```

To speed up the process, and potentially avoid the drive dying in mid stride, you might also try increasing the byte size from the default 512 (which makes dd read sector-by-sector, which is slow) to something larger such as 4K (which is eight times as large):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXX bs=4K conv=noerror
```

Note: With a larger byte size, skipped errors may leave sections of readable data slightly-less than the byte size you choose, but it's still unlikely that anyone would be able to get anything from those sections after the entire disk has been run through the process.

Besides that, I'm sure hard drive manufacturers properly dispose of hard drives that get returned for warranty replacement, in case the drive does fail before you were able to fully complete the overwrite process.

Comment: `man dd` shows "noerror" means "continue after read errors"

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a power-user solution, but if the write errors are rare, you might just want to continue manually after their occurence.

You could theoretically script something to do that automatically, but it's not that trivial, and I'd rather write a tool to do the trick than bother with scripting dd..

```
   seek=BLOCKS
          skip BLOCKS obs-sized blocks at start of output
```

Comment: ... or use dd-rescue...

Comment: ... would dd-rescue handle *write* errors correctly?